# Typo3 Gridelements - Access rights or multisite use

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-gridelements

I'm using GridElements 7.0 with TYPO3 7.6 on a **multisite** instance of TYPO3.

How can I restrict the use of a grid element for site A but not for site B?  Or user X have rights to element "1 column for site A" and user Y to "1 column for site B".

I know that I can restrict the use of content elements or grid elements in the definition of a column such as

```
columns {
  1 {
    colPos = 1
    allowed = text,textpic
    allowedGridTypes = 1, 2
  }
}
```

but it doesn't solved my problem.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use typoscript condition `[PIDinRootline = pages-uid]` for this. Like below.

More Typoscript condition [Click Here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html)

In your setup Ts like this.

```
[PIDinRootline = site-a-rootPid]
// Here your Typoscript for site A
[end]

[PIDinRootline = site-b-rootPid]
// Here your Typoscript for site B
[end]
```

Comment: This is working only if the gridelements are created by pure TS. How can I do it if my gridelements are created with the BE module?  It seems that every gridelements created in the BE module is available to all sites on the instance even if my PID is not in the root.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TSConfig to configure available gridelements on a per tree basis https://gist.github.com/noelboss/7582267

So do that for the specific page trees and you should be good to go